# C++ Read file with extended ASCII

Tags: c++, unicode

I have a text file that contains a path. The path can be anything and can contain many different exotic characters. For the sake of example let's say it contains this:

```
C:\России общий приговор\file.dat
```

Now I'm using wifstream to fetch the line...

```
wifstream myfile(path_to_txt_file);
wstring path = L"";
if (!getline(myfile, path)) cout << "Couldn't open file!" << endl;
```

The problem arises when I want to check if the file in the path variable exists (I'm using Boost, but it doesn't really matter), it returns 0 even though it is present.

```
cout << boost::filesystem::exists(path) << endl; // 0
cout << boost::filesystem::exists(L"C:\\России общий приговор\\file.dat") << endl; // 1
```

Passing the variable in there returns 0, but hard-coding the path works, what's going on?
Do I need to set some locale settings? If so, how do I get this to work for everyone? Russian, Chinese, Swedish etc.

Comment: It would help if you knew what the encoding really was. It isn't extended ASCII which in any case is a non-specific and ill-specified thing. There is no single extended ASCII. Looks like you've got UTF-16 encoded text on Windows.

Comment: Compare path and your string byte-by-byte to see the difference, e.g. print them out in hexa. A possible difference is for example having a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file.

Comment: According to Notepad++, the text file is "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM", the file is generated by another program which I have no control over.

Comment: Presumably you printed `path` to see what it contains. That would surely be the first debugging step.

Comment: I did, but the console couldn't display the russian characters, so I got
C:\╨á╨╛╤ü╤ü╨╕╨╕ ╨╛╨▒╤ë╨╕╨╣ ╨┐╤Ç╨╕╨│╨╛╨▓╨╛╤Ç\file.dat (wcout)

Comment: This is not UTF-8 I can assure you. It is most probably cp-1251 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)

Comment: @DavidNorgren Please show us the actual raw byte value of this, it will solve the encoding question.

Comment: @DavidNorgren The console won't show "extended" characters. Print the **hexadecimal** values instead for **each** character in **both** of your strings so that you can do a comparison

Comment: @Andrey "It is most probably "cp-1251". Huh? Every other character is '╨' or '╤', which are usually 0xD0 and 0xD1. That's Cyrillic text in UTF-8 if I ever saw one.

Comment: The characters from the file are
43 3a 5c d0 a0 d0 be d1 81 d1 81 d0 b8 d0 b8 20 d0 be d0 b1 d1 89 d0 b8 d0 b9 20 d0 bf d1 80 d0 b8 d0 b3 d0 be d0 b2 d0 be d1 80 5c 66 69 6c 65 2e 64 61 74

When hardcoding it prints as
43 3a 5c 420 43e 441 441 438 438 20 43e 431 449 438 439 20 43f 440 438 433 43e 432 43e 440 5c 66 69 6c 65 2e 64 61 74 0

Comment: You have  UTF-8-encoded data, just as Notepad++ suggests. You need a library that can read and transcode UTF-8. Note Windows has no UTF-8 locale so the native C++ I/O library is of little help here. C++11 has UTF-8-enabled I/O but many implementations don't support it yet.

Comment: @n.m.: Although Windows does not have a UTF-8 locale and in general has poor support for UTF-8, the [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx) function does allow converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16 by using the `CP_UTF8` code page identifier.

Comment: @n.m. you are right, my bad